# Dataframe data into scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I'm trying to create a scatter plot below or just remove the lines between points to improve how the graphs look. My code below works great for line graphs but when I try to plot for scatter graphs it doesnt output anything. Any advice on how I might retool the below for a scatter or just points instead of a drawn line between points.

MergedData represents my dataframe with me wanting to plot demand and drybulb vs demand unconnected by lines.

```
n=0
while n<24:
    n+=1
    print(n)
    MergedData=pd.merge(WE, DE, how='outer')
    MergedData= MergedData[MergedData.DEMAND != 0]
    MergedData.dropna(axis=1, how='any')

    MergedData= MergedData[1:8700]

    MergedData = MergedData[MergedData.Hour == n]

    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

    y1 = MergedData['DEMAND']

    ax1.set_ylabel('Demand')
    ax1.set_xlabel('Temperature')
    ax1.set_title('')
    ax1.plot(MergedData['DryBulb'], y1, 'r-')
    ax1.legend(labels=("Demand",),bbox_to_anchor=(0.05, 0.975), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)

    print("Demand and Temperature Correlation for hour ",sep='')
    print(n)    
    print(MergedData['DEMAND'].corr(MergedData['DryBulb']))
```

Comment: The code you show seems to produce a line plot. There is little use in showing the code that works fine. Instead show the code you have problems with. Make sure it is a [mcve] of the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Plotted below works for dataframe in scatter plot loop. Not sure why I was having so many issues with this earlier.

```
n=0
while n<24:
    n+=1
    print(n)
    MergedData=pd.merge(WE, DE, how='outer')
    MergedData= MergedData[MergedData.DEMAND != 0]
    MergedData.dropna(axis=1, how='any')

    MergedData= MergedData[1:8700]

    MergedData = MergedData[MergedData.Hour == n]

    plt.scatter(MergedData['DryBulb'], MergedData['DEMAND'])
    plt.show()

    print("Demand and Temperature Correlation for hour ",sep='')
    print(n)    
    print(MergedData['DEMAND'].corr(MergedData['DryBulb']))
```